Python-binance and asyncio
I'm trying to get some data from Binance (using python-binance package). My very simple code:
import asyncio
from binance.client import AsyncClient

async def get_data(client):
  res = await client.get_klines(symbol='BTCUSDT', interval='15m', limit=99)
  print(res)

async def main():
  client = await AsyncClient.create()
  asyncio.create_task(get_data(client=client))

asyncio.run(main())

This code does not work.  Execution stops at res = await client.get_klines(...). But if I change the way I run get_data(), then it starts working:
import asyncio
from binance.client import AsyncClient

async def get_data(client):
  res = await client.get_klines(symbol='BTCUSDT', interval='15m', limit=99)
  print(res)

async def main():
  client = await AsyncClient.create()
  await get_data(client=client)

asyncio.run(main())

The code above works well, but it does not fit my neeeds. I need to run multiple tasks working with Binance API.

The problem is that main() does not wait for other tasks to finish, so we need to tell it to wait for them. For example using asyncio.gather():
import asyncio
from binance.client import AsyncClient

async def get_data(client):
  res = await client.get_klines(symbol='BTCUSDT', interval='15m', limit=99)
  print(res)

async def main():
  client = await AsyncClient.create()
  await asyncio.gather(
    get_data(client=client)
  )

asyncio.run(main())

